# Google Sheets - Trouble importing XML on particular page

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Attempting to use ImportXML in Google Sheets to retrieve a specific piece of text but am having trouble after searching my ass off for answers.

Hoping someone here can help correct the problem.

The page is: https://www.afi.com.au
And the text I'm wanting to import is in the pink box:

[image]

Here's where I'm at with the code, I've attempted to retrieve the XPath but it doesn't like what I have, I'm sure someone here will spot the prob in a heartbeat...

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.afi.com.au","//body[@class='entry-homepage type-homepage']/div[@class='page page-home']/div[@class='page__item']/div[@class='js-evo7-component']/div[@class='hero']/div[@class='hero__inner-root rellax']/div[@class='hero__inner']/div[@class='container']/div[@class='grid']/div[@class='grid__item one-third palm-one-whole']/div[@class='hero__share-price']/div[@class='price-number']//text()")
```

Comment: @Wristy Manchego Although the question has already been closed, can I propose a workaround for retrieving the value you need as other answer?

Comment: Yeah, of course mate. I’m still hunting a solution to import this value into a sheet.

Comment: @Wristy Manchego Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified formula as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for this. I certainly will when I next get a chance. On initial viewing, it looks like you’re on the money.

Comment: @Wristy Manchego Thank you for replying. If that was useful, I'm glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this workaround? In this workaround, the data is retrieved using a xpath, and the value is retrieved using a regular expression. It seems that the retrieved data is updated when the page is retrieved. So I used this method. The modified formula is as follows. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample formula:

In this sample formula, `http://www.afi.com.au` is put in the cell "A1".

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='js-evo7-component']/@data-config"),"netAssetBacking"":{""price"":""([\d.]+)")
```

1. Retrieve data using the xpath of `//div[@class='js-evo7-component']/@data-config` with `IMPORTXML()`.
2. Retrieve the value using the regular expression of `netAssetBacking"":{""price"":""([\d.]+)` with `REGEXEXTRACT()`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)

Comment: Apologies Tenaike, I've only just had a chance to test your formula. It works perfectly. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @Wristy Manchego Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Even if it's the site that the values are put in the tag by executing Javascript, there is a case that the values for using with Javascript can be directly retrieved by analyzing HTML and Javascript. But it is not all sites. In your situation, I had the luck to use this.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I'm attempting to make use of this with other pages but I think I'm missing some fundamentals here. How would I go about getting the "NAV Price" (numbers only) from this page: https://www.vanguardinvestments.com.au/adviser/adv/investments/product.html#/fundDetail/etf/portId=8213/assetCode=equity/?overview
Do I need to find the Xpath from somewhere?

Comment: @Wristy Manchego Thank you for replying. About your question of your replying, can you post it as new question including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. Because your question of your replying is different from your initial question. When you posted it as new question and several answers are posted to it, I think that the information will be also useful for other users. Also I would like to confirm your question. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

that won't be possible. the piece of information you try to scrape is controlled by JavaScript and Google Sheets can't read JS at all. you can test this simply just by disabling JS on the given website:

[image: 0]

Comment: Ah, thanks for investigating. I’ll have to find an alternate source for that number. Appreciated.